# Custom function to check if variables in array are set

Tags: php, function

What I'm trying to do is write one function to reuse vs writing out an if statement every time.

If statement:

```
if (!isset($value)){ echo 'null';}else{ echo $value;}
```

Function:

```
function isSetTest($value){
    if ( !isset($value)){
       $value = NULL;
    }
    return $value;
}

echo'name'.isSetTest($value);
```

Function works but I still get the "undefined" error message which is what i'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Pass the variable name as string an use variable variables

Comment: The function is returning $value regardless of anything. And whats going on with $field? that doesn't go anywhere either.

Comment: Sorry fixed the "$field". yes it will return the $value if its there if its not then its set to null vs undefined.

Comment: Is there actually an array involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass by reference instead, so that no processing of the variable is done until you want it:

```
function isSetTest(&$value) { // note the &
    if (!isset($value)) {
       $value = NULL;
    }
    return $value;
}
```

You can shorten this a bit:

```
function isSetTest(&$value) {
    return isset($value) ? $value : null;
}
```

I have a function that does something similar, except you can provide an optional default value in the case that the variable is not set:

```
function isset_or(&$value, $default = null) {
    return isset($value) ? $value : $default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is, that you still pass an undefined variable to your function, so that's why you still get your undefined error.

One way to solve this now, is that you pass your variable name as a string and then use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), to check if it exists, e.g.

```
function isSetTest($value){
    global $$value;
    if ( !isset($$value)){
       $$value = NULL;
    }
    return $$value;
}

echo'name'.isSetTest("value");
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://3v4l.org/ebUAB)

Comment: The problem with using `global` is that the variable must, obviously, be in the global scope for it to work, which it (hopefully) won't be in 99% of cases.